# How can I temporarily save survey data for a guest and retrieve it upon login/registration in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a survey on my WordPress website. When users complete the survey, they will be redirected to the registration page. I want to temporarily save their survey data and retrieve it once they log in or register.

I've attempted to use sessions for this purpose, but I often encounter problems when trying to retrieve the session data. I prefer not to use cookies. Is there any another way to achieve this in WordPress?

---

I've been using the following code and was able to successfully retrieve session data during user registration/login. However, it suddenly stopped working. While the session data is set upon survey completion, it can't be retrieved during user registration/login.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
//save submitted survey data
add_action('fluentform/submission_inserted', 'your_custom_after_submission_function', 20, 3);
function your_custom_after_submission_function($entryId, $formData, $form)
{
  if($form->id == 3){
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        if(!session_id()) {
            session_start();
        }
        $_SESSION["caseDetail"] = $formData;
        error_log('session caseDetail saved: ' . print_r($_SESSION["caseDetail"], true));
    }else{
        update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'caseDetail', $formData);
    }
  }
}

//retrieve session data when register
add_action( 'um_post_registration_approved_hook', 'my_custom_registration_function_v', 10, 3 );
function my_custom_registration_function_v($user_id, $submitted_data, $form_data){
    error_log('um_post_registration_approved_hook fires');
    if(isset($_SESSION["caseDetail"])){
        error_log('session caseDetail:' . print_r($_SESSION["caseDetail"], true));
    }else{
        error_log('session is not set');
    }
}

//retrieve session data when login
add_action( 'um_on_login_before_redirect', 'my_login_function_x', 1, 1 );
function my_login_function_x($user_id){
    error_log('um_on_login_before_redirect hook fires');
    if(isset($_SESSION["caseDetail"])){
        error_log('session caseDetail:' . print_r($_SESSION["caseDetail"], true));
    }else{
        error_log('session is not set');
    }
}
```

Comment: WordPress doesn't natively support PHP sessions, and their behavior can be unpredictable due to how WordPress handles state and user data. Instead of relying on sessions or cookies, you can use WordPress's transient API to temporarily store survey data.

Comment: @user580950  I need to save data for each guest individually, and retrieve it separately when they register or log in. How can I achieve this?